# Admob with designed for families not showing ads

Tags: android, admob

I want to add my app to "Designed for families", but for mixed audience, so as [official documentation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en) said I change my ads request like this:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .build();
```

The problem is that when I put the "is_designed_for_families" extra, no ads is displayed.

```
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

**Update**: I know that error 3 means that admob doesn't have an ad to show at the moment, but I have set "test device" so it should show test ads.

I haven't marked as "Designed for families" in Google Play yet, because I want to check that the ads are displaying correctly.

Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: The same as mine problem. I have got answer from Admob support this is a matter of fewer requests in "Designed for families" and some Google issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Error code 3](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) means that admbob doesn't have an ad to show at the moment. 
This means that your code implementation is correct but at the moment there are no ads to show.

Also, if you have just implemented admob, it could take some time for it to start sending you ads. This is called "Warming up" and it could take up to a couple of days (depending on the number of ad requests).

**Update:** If you receive a NO FILL error (code: 3)  while testing "Designed for families" ads, the test ad will not be shown.
To test if your admob implementation works, just remove the extra "is_designed_for_families".

This is the intended behaviour of the admob sdk. [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/is_designed_for_families%7Csort:relevance/google-admob-ads-sdk/rOZH8y3Nz3s/ZamyR46UAwAJ)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have set the test device, so I guess that it should show test ads. And, it is an old ad id that now I need to be designed for families

Comment: Thanks for the update, how did you know that? Can I check that in the official documentation? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! From a response of a dev member of Admob Mobile SDK.

I have added the link to the answer. Feel free to accept it if you feel like it.

Comment: I have contacted admob to contrast this information, and you are right, so I mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @MartaRodriguez, so have you ads now in your application ? we applied for "Design for families" and it approved now. we are facing the same issues which you mentioned. so need to know about the status of ads of your app ?

Comment: @JKPatel We included our app in "Designed for families" section about 2 weeks ago with Admob changes to apply "Designed for families" conditions but there are not ads to show. Nowadays, I think that if you include your app in the "Designed for families" section you can only monetize it with in-app purchases or with a paid app.

Comment: @MartaRodriguez, Useful information. i am thinking as you are.  So now only one way to monetize in "Design for Families" & it is In-App Purchase.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to exit "Design for Families" program?

Comment: Hello, the same problem as mine, I have got the answer from Google Admob team, that Designed for families generate fewer requests and they are working on some issues. The problems is that google didn't publish my app without entering to "Designed for families" and when I try to quit this program, they write me I MUST stay in "Designed for families", because my app is child directed.   Let's say simple it is correct from Google. They make you engage in the program and then limit you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change AdMob with another because AdMob look at your app settings in the play store and check if its a "familey" app
see this website

https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-alternative-to-AdMob-for-Android-ad-platform